# RewriteRules directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this rules into my `.htaaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ /index.php?pg=$1
```

Now, the result work, if I type `www.example.com/try/` it rewrite `www.example.com/index.php?pg=try`

The problem is that, all the links into the page are one level down. 
Ex. if I whant the image `www.example.com/img/image.png` I have to type `<img src="../img/image.png" />` even if the index page location is `www.example.com/index.php`.

How to solve the problem?

I can't add the `../` to every link in the page.

Comment: Just make your img/css/js URLs relative to the root and not to current document: i.e. instead of current `<img src="img/image.png" />` use `<img src="/img/image.png" />` -- all such links should start with leading slash `/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the trailing slash (ex, `example.com/try`), then everything will work.

Is that good enough?